# Bluemix dashboard not displaying on iPad

Tags: ios, mobile, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to get my bluemix.net dashboard display on an iPad 4 running iOS 8.2 (yeah it is time to upgrade). After logging on, my dashboard only shows a horizontal bar on the top of the screen. That's it. I can change the URL to get to the catalog, which displays correctly. I can see that I'm logged in, but I can't see my dashboard.

No issues trying this on a laptop. On the iPad I've deleted my cookies and cache. I also installed FireFox but had the same issue.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Spiros

Comment: I also experienced a problem trying to load Bluemix dashboard on my ipad.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't like making major changes while trying to troubleshoot, but I just upgraded to iOS 9.1 and now I can access Bluemix without a problem.